# Enter amount in the textbox automatically when selected from dropdown in php

Tags: javascript, jquery

When value is selected from the dropdown automatically amount is to be entered in textbox for that particular selected dropdown.

1. When the user selects the date the events present in particular date will appear in the dropdown menu.
2. When user selects the event from the dropdown the amount  for that particular date as to be entered automatically in the textbox.

Below is my code which selects the date and populates dropdown with the events available for that day. I dont know how can I enter amount automatically when for the selected dropdown value.

```js
 

<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var dayNo = date.getDay();
  var mindate = (7 - dayNo);
  var d = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'];
  var event = ['6.30 am : Mass in English']
  var event1 = [' 6.30pm : Mass in English (St.Alphonsa Novena)']
  var event2 = ['6.00pm - 7.00pm : Adoration followed by Mass & Snacks']
  var event3 = ['5.00pm : Adoration followed by mass at 5.30pm in Tamil', '6.30pm - 7.00pm : Adoration in English followed by mass']
  var event4 = [' 6.30pm : mass in English (Sunday liturgy)']
  var event5 = ['7.00am : Mass in Kannada', '8.00am : Mass in Tamil', '9.30am : Mass in English']

  //Lest assume this is  event from database
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: mindate,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var today = new Date(dateText);
      var a = (d[today.getDay()]);
      $('#slDay').val(d[today.getDay()])
      var html = '';
      $('#slDay').html('');
      if (d[today.getDay()] == 'sun')
        $.each(event5, function(index, value) {
          html += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
        });
      if (d[today.getDay()] == 'mon')
        $.each(event, function(index, value) {
          html += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
        });
      if (d[today.getDay()] == 'tue')
        $.each(event, function(index, value) {
          html += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
        });
      $('#slDay').append(html);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="w3l-user">
  <label class="head">Select Date<span class="w3l-star"> * </span></label>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" placeholder="Select Date" required="">
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="gender">
  <label class="head">Select Mass<span class="w3l-star"> * </span></label>
  <select class="form-control" required="" id='slDay' name="day">
    <option value="">---SELECT---</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="w3l-user">
  <label class="head">Amount<span class="w3l-star"> * </span></label>
  <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" required="" />
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Could you please add code snippet here with all Required JS ?

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: Where is amount related to event?

Comment: I have not yet added. I had no idea how to do it

Comment: Could you please add datepicker.js too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working code. You need to make slight changes in array. I have changed

```
var event = {'10': '6.30 am : Mass in English', '9': '6.30 am : Mass in English'};
```

set key value pair where key is amount and value is event.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bhumi/mtyhxu5j/2/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var dayNo = date.getDay();
    var mindate = (7 - dayNo);
    var d = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'];
    var event = {'10': '6.30 am : Mass in English', '9': '6.30 am : Mass in English'};
    var event1 = [' 6.30pm : Mass in English (St.Alphonsa Novena)']
    var event2 = ['6.00pm - 7.00pm : Adoration followed by Mass & Snacks']
    var event3 = ['5.00pm : Adoration followed by mass at 5.30pm in Tamil', '6.30pm - 7.00pm : Adoration in English followed by mass']
    var event4 = [' 6.30pm : mass in English (Sunday liturgy)']
    var event5 = ['7.00am : Mass in Kannada', '8.00am : Mass in Tamil', '9.30am : Mass in English']

    //Lest assume this is  event from database
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      firstDay: 1,
      minDate: mindate,
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var today = new Date(dateText);
        var a = (d[today.getDay()]);
        $('#slDay').val(d[today.getDay()])
        var html = '';
        $('#slDay').html('');
        if (d[today.getDay()] == 'sun')
          $.each(event5, function(index, value) {
            html += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
          });
        if (d[today.getDay()] == 'mon')
          $.each(event, function(index, value) {console.log(value); console.log(index);
            html += '<option value="' + index + '" >' + value + '</option>'
          });
        if (d[today.getDay()] == 'tue')
          $.each(event, function(index, value) {
            html += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
          });
        $('#slDay').append(html);
        $('#slDay').trigger('change');
      }
    });
//    var event_amount['6.30 am : Mass in English'] =  '10.00';

    $('#slDay').on('change', function(e){
        $('#amount').val(this.value);
    });
  });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="w3l-user">
  <label class="head">Select Date<span class="w3l-star"> * </span></label>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" placeholder="Select Date" required="">
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="gender">
  <label class="head">Select Mass<span class="w3l-star"> * </span></label>
  <select class="form-control" required="" id='slDay' name="day">
    <option value="">---SELECT---</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="w3l-user">
  <label class="head">Amount<span class="w3l-star"> * </span></label>
  <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" required="" />
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: select  date from monday. I have done change for "mon" and event only. Like 2018-05-21